# parameter not working stored procedure

Tags: t-sql

```
--  This query works using the split function
SELECT AssignUserID,* FROM dbo.Task WHERE TaskID in (SELECT * FROM udf_Split ('1269469,1359508',','))


--this script using the @TasksToUpdate parameter does not work.  
--If I replace the parameter @TasksToUpdate with the string in the where clause then it does work
DECLARE @NewUser varchar 
DECLARE @TasksToUpdate varchar 
DECLARE @UpdateUser VARCHAR(30)

SET @NewUser = 'aaronteamlead'
SET @TasksToUpdate = '1269469,1359508'
SET @UpdateUser = 'updateusername'

UPDATE dbo.Task
SET AssignUserID = @NewUser,LastUpdatedDt=getdate(),LastUpdatedUser=@UpdateUser
WHERE TaskID in (SELECT * FROM udf_Split (@TasksToUpdate,','))
```

Comment: Specify a length for `DECLARE @TasksToUpdate varchar`.  When no length is specified, it defaults to `VARCHAR(1)`.

Comment: Use varchar(max) for the most flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

DMason was correct.

"Specify a length for DECLARE @TasksToUpdate varchar. When no length is specified, it defaults to VARCHAR(1). "